# How can i get to a bot to respond to dms

Tags: javascript, discord.js, concept

So working with discordjs and was wondering if it is possible to have my bot respond to commands sent in dms with the bot is there a way to listen to DMs? Example: user DMs the bot with !test and the bot would respond in DMs with success?

Comment: what version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Then when setting `new Discord.Client()` make sure to add the `"CHANNEL"` partial and the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` intent... You must also allow this intent in your developer portal else you will get an intents permissions error.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  partials: ["CHANNEL"],
  intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES]
})
```

and then in the `messageCreate` listener this is how you listen for a DM.

```js
if(command === "test" && message.channel.type === "DM"){
  message.channel.send("Success!")
}
```

this is checking if the channel the message is received in is a direct messaging channel, if not it'll return, else it will respond with with "Success!"

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```js
if(message.channel.DMChannel) {
   message.author.send("Success")
}
```

I am not sure but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(message.channel.type == "DM"){ // if it's v12 just type change it to "dm"
// do sth

}
```